# Is there an alternative to guillemets in py2neo?

Tags: python, neo4j, jupyter-notebook, quotes, py2neo

I need to use the cypher.execute to build a database in python for neo4j with py2neo. But my jupyther (ipython notebook) is not recognizing the << >> characters in this statement. is there an alternative?

```
cypher.execute("CREATE (a {name:{a}})-[:«rel»]->(b:«labels» {name:{b}})",
               a="Alice", rel="KNOWS", labels=["Human Being", "Employee"], b="Bob")
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not recognizing'? Can't you just leave them out?

Comment: @MartinPreusse I am not sure one can substitute the node label or some other bits of the cypher query using the normal means.  See the bottom of the first section here:  http://py2neo.org/2.0/cypher.html